# What are suitable predictive analytics models for data from multiple sensors?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, linear-regression

I am a newbie in the field of AI/ML. I am trying to implement predictive analytics model on the data generated and collected every minute from a device with sensors.

I have two questions:

1. What are various ML algorithms I can use to predict the number of
   people in a room given temperature, humidity, luminosity, and motion
   { 0 | 1 }?
2. What other things can we predict using the above data from the
   sensor that is deployed in a closed room?

**Context:**

The device sends temperature, humidity, luminosity, and motion(yes/no) in real-time. I deployed this device in a closed room and started collecting data. Now I want to use this data to predict the number of people in the room using the data collected. I believe a multiple (linear/poly) regression model will help me in achieving this but, wanted to know if there are any other algorithms or any other use cases I can look into.

Comment: I expect there will be a lot of error margin (as I know people who can't sit still, and other who are extremely sedentary; some sweat a lot and other's not so much) but it's an extraordinarily interesting problem.  Welcome to AI!

Comment: What about sound?  Humans make a lot of sound (breathing/heartbeat vibrations etc) depending on how good your sensors are and where they are located...?  Just an idea...

Comment: @DukeZhou one here, is trying to broaden the scope of the question.

Comment: @DenizC That's a great idea.  Dogs will generally pant, or their collars give a little jingle.  Wonder if the sensors can pick up things like heartbeat though...

Comment: Google remote heartbeat sensors - military has been using them for years to detect heartbeats through walls.